# How do you use Plack::Middleware::Session with a Twiggy server?

Tags: perl, session, plack

I have a [`Twiggy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Twiggy) based perl server:

```
my $app = sub { my $req = Plack::Request->new(shift); ... };
my $twiggy = Twiggy::Server->new(port => $port);
$twiggy->register_service($app);
```

It works fine, but now I want to add session management to it (to handle user authentication). I see there is a [`Plack::Middleware::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Middleware::Session) module on CPAN, but based on the docs for it and Twiggy I don't know how to use the two together. I've reason to believe it might be possible because in my $app I'm dealing with Plack stuff.

Alternatively to using `Plack::Middleware::Session`, is there some other way I can easily get and set cookie values and maintain session state for authentication purposes? (Each page load requested by the user is handled in a new fork of the server.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just string it together. The `builder` funtion of Plack::Builder will wrap your app in a Middleware (or several). Then you just pass that as a new app to Twiggy.

```
use Plack::Builder;
use Twiggy::Server;

my $app = sub {
    my $env = shift;
    my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
    my $session = $env->{'psgix.session'};
    return [
        200,
        [ 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' ],
        [ "Hello, you've been here for ", $session->{counter}++, "th time!" ],
    ];
};

$app = builder {
    enable 'Session', store => 'File';
    $app;
};

my $twiggy = Twiggy::Server->new(port => 3000);
$twiggy->register_service($app);

AE::cv->recv;
```

Note that `builder` will return a new app, but it will not end up in `$app` unless you assign it. You could also just put the `builder` into the `register_service` like this:

```
my $twiggy = Twiggy::Server->new(port => 3000);
$twiggy->register_service(builder {
    enable 'Session', store => 'File';
    $app;
});
```

---

Or of course you could get rid of Twiggy::Server and run the `twiggy` command line tool or `plackup` with twiggy.

Comment: I've sort of got it working: I can see that it sets a cookie, but things I set in my $session are not available the next time I look in there. I presumed that store => 'File' would handle the fact that in my $app I do a (non-blocking) fork call. How is the getting-back-your-session-variables side of things supposed to work?

Comment: I think that is just kind of done automatically. The Middleware will modify `$env` in the wrapper around your app, so the key `psgix.session` is just magically there.

Answer (score 1):

The joy of PSGI is that everything plugs together the same way every time.

You expand a PSGI app with middleware, using the `build` function supplied by Plack::Builder.

I haven't tried it, but I expect that something like this would work:

```
use Twiggy::Server;
use Plack::Builder;
use Plack::Middleware::Session;

my $app = sub { my $req = Plack::Request->new(shift); ... };

$app = builder {
  enable 'Session';
  $app;
}

my $twiggy = Twiggy::Server->new(port => $port);
$twiggy->register_service($app);
```